# How to customize downloadHandler-button in Rmarkdown document

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

In shiny a `downloadHandler` is combined with an `actionButton`/`downloadButton` in the UI-Part. Thus you easily can change the buttons label by typing:

```
downloadButton("btn_export", "Export")
```

Here is a little shinyapp with just one button to export some example data:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    downloadButton("btn_export", "Export")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    data <- mtcars
    
    output$btn_export <- downloadHandler(
        filename = function() {
            paste0("shiny_", Sys.Date(), ".csv")
        },
        content = function(file) {
            write.csv(data, file)
        }
    )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

In Rmarkdown the `downloadHandler` is added directly to a code chunk:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
downloadHandler(
  filename = function() {
    paste0("rmd_", Sys.Date(), ".csv")
  },
  content = function(file) {
    write.csv(data, file)
  }
)
```
````

How can I change the label of the download button?

A complete example:

````
---
title: "test"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r data_prep, include=FALSE}
data <- mtcars
```

```{r download, echo=FALSE}
downloadHandler(
  filename = function() {
    paste0("rmd_", Sys.Date(), ".csv")
  },
  content = function(file) {
    write.csv(data, file)
  }
)
```
````

**Edit:**

The upper reproducible minimal example might be too minimal. The `downloadHandler` in my real Rmarkdown document is rendering a static Rmd-report for download:

```
downloadHandler(filename = function() {
    return("CaRe.html")
  }, content = function(file) {
     rmarkdown::render(input = "CaRe_static.Rmd", 
                       output_file = file,
                       params = list(in_rohdaten = input$in_rohdaten$datapath,
                                     in_kunde = input$in_kunde,
                                     in_kampagne = input$in_kampagne,
                                     in_auftrag = input$in_auftrag,
                                     in_datum = input$in_datum
     ))
  }, contentType = "text/html"
)
```

Just in case that is relevant for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Argh, it's so simple if you carefully read the manual. Sorry for wasting your time.

You can use the `outputArgs` parameter of `downloadHandler` to change the label of the download-button:

````
---
title: "test"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r data_prep, include=FALSE}
data <- mtcars
```

```{r download, echo=FALSE}
downloadHandler(
  filename = function() {
    paste0("rmd_", Sys.Date(), ".csv")
  },
  content = function(file) {
    write.csv(data, file)
  },
  outputArgs = list(label = "Export")  # <--- That's it!
)
```
````

Comment: Glad that you solved it and very happy to learn something new :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to do it using `downloadHandler()` but you can try *downloadthis* package.

````
---
title: "test"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r, include=FALSE}
library(downloadthis)

data <- mtcars
```

```{r, echo=FALSE}
download_this(mtcars,
  output_name = "mtcars data set",
  output_extension = ".csv",
  button_label = "Download mtcars",
  button_type = "warning",
  has_icon = TRUE,
  icon = "fa fa-save"
)
````

Comment: Thanks @Yuli. Unfortunately I'm getting an error when I run the document: `Error in : [ENOENT] Failed to remove '/var/folders/xc/kqx0jp0s2md1dw9z9gnlzzldnk_zm2/T/Rtmp1kVyIP/file14c416cc14a19.csv': no such file or directory`.

Comment: Maybe my example code is too minimal. In fact the `downloadHandler` in my document renders a static Rmd-report for download. Is that possible with `downloadthis`? I edited my question.

Comment: One more ;). From package-website: "This package provides a wrapper around `bsplus::bs_button()`, which has to goal to provide a download button in HTML outputs from R Markdown without the need to have `runtime: shiny.`". So will this work in my dynamic case, as my Rmd is running on a shiny server and the download is created from user input?